# Erased gcc4.6... shouldn't have

Tags: gcc

So... after isntalling gcc4.7, I found I had gcc4.5, 4.6 and 4.7. After configuring alternatives, when typing gcc --version it said it was 4.7, but I was not sure that Qtcreator were using the right one, so I decided to erase 4.5 and 4.6.

And... I shouldn't have done that. Now, even when I reinstalled 4.6 with aptitude, gcc command is not found (/usr/bin/gcc: NO such file or directoy).

I need to fix this or I can't continue working. I'm only interested in having 4.7. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
```

This will recreate the missing symbolic link to the actual gcc executable (gcc in default installation is just a symbolic link to gcc-4.6).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I guess that's the commando used to create a link to gcc-4.7, isn't it?